# How do I select based on a string another pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one main dataframe and several FX-Rate dataframes. The main one is loaded with data and with one column, which tells you the corresponding FX-Rate Table.

If i read one row in the main table, it tells me at the end: FX_TABLE_2
This comes as a string. How do I open than the FX_TABLE_2, which is a dataframe object?

e.g.

```
FX_TABLE_1 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_1',index_col=0)
FX_TABLE_2 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_2',index_col=0)
FX_TABLE_3 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_3',index_col=0)
FX_TABLE_4 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_4',index_col=0)
FX_TABLE_5 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_5',index_col=0)
FX_TABLE_6 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_6',index_col=0)
FX_TABLE_7 = pd.read_excel(path6, 'FX_TABLE_7',index_col=0)


for ind in Mainframe.index:
    ###### select FX Table for row
    FX_Table = Mainframe['FX_Table'][ind]
    print(type(FX_Table))
    print(type(FX_TABLE_5))
```

so i get a str for the first element, but based on this str out of the FX_Table column, i want to choose the correct dataframe. If i print the second element from the code, it is a <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> and cannot be opened with a <class 'str'>.

Could anyone help? would be really nice!

It is basically select a dataframe from a output of a formula which is a str-element

Comment: I have not completely understood your question, as after `FX_TABLE_XXXX = pd.read_excel(path6` your table is already loaded and active.
The main question would be, - what do you want to do with all these tables?
If all of them have the same headers(amount of columns, named in the same way), - logical approach would be to loop via folder and load ALL files into one large DataFrame and continue from there

Comment: Hi NoobVB, yes they are loaded and active. Loading in one big dataframe is not the issue. The FX_Tables are in one file, but different tabs for different years. My main table has a different structure.  I want to calculate the values in the main table with the corresponding fx_rates table.

So if I check the column in the main table, which is giving me the correct FX-Rates-Table, i get a <str> element, but want to open than a <dataframe element>. How do i do this then?

Comment: try to merge all frames into new large dataframe based on "FX_TABLE" value which you have on your main one, - so you will have all columns and can start calculations on it. Later, - keep or transfer only the columns you actually need for your final result.
If all corresponding tables, are missing FX_TABLE column, you can create one while opening the file/sheet and pass that FX_TABLE value to the new column based on file or sheet name, - so you will have unique identifier

Comment: the merge will not work unfortunately. In the main table, the reference to the correct FX rates table is in the Table column. I want to read this value as shown in the code via the column value e.g. "FX_TABLE_2". However, when I read that out, I have a Str element. Now I need a conversion or a trick how to open the correct FX_TABLE (actually a dataframe element) with it then.

Comment: it would be easier if you would paste some (lets say 10 rows) of your main table, also of relevant table and would also show the result your expect to get

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want something like `globals()[f'FX_TABLE_{ind}']`

Comment: @noobVB check the latest image please. i think it makes it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like you have quite a misconception here.

Please note, you cannot load dataframe into another as they are separate objects, however, you can load data from one df into another in different ways, using `concat`, `merge` and etc.

small example for you below, I hope it will lead you forward, it has comments of each step:

```
main = {
  "EXP": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "EXP2": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "FX_Table": ["FX_TABLE_1", "FX_TABLE_2","FX_TABLE_1","FX_TABLE_2"],
    "Currency": ["EUR", "EUR", "CNY", "GBP"]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
main = pd.DataFrame(main)

path6 = r'C:\Sandbox\test.xlsx'
Excel_File = pd.ExcelFile(path6)  # reads whole excelFile at once
dfs_dict = {sh:Excel_File.parse(sh) for sh in Excel_File.sheet_names} # loading each sheet to DataFrame and each dataframe to dictionary
print(dfs_dict.keys()) # will show each sheet name loaded
print(dfs_dict['FX_TABLE_2'])  # will show data from single DataFrame by it's key in the dictionary (which is the same as sheet name)

#adding new column to each DataFrame saved in the dictionary:
for key in dfs_dict.keys():
 dfs_dict[key]['Sheet_Name'] = key

print(dfs_dict['FX_TABLE_2']) # will show DataFrame with new column which can be used as unique ID

# now you can add data from other tables into Main or New_main dataframe, - up to you. I will use Sheet Name and Currencty as unique ID for merging
New_main = pd.merge(main, dfs_dict['FX_TABLE_1'], how='outer', left_on=['FX_Table', 'Currency'], right_on=['Sheet_Name','currency'])

print(New_main)

   EXP  EXP2    FX_Table Currency currency  ...  2008  2009  2010  2011  Sheet_Name
0    1     1  FX_TABLE_1      EUR      EUR  ...   3.0  3.05   3.1  3.15  FX_TABLE_1
1    2     2  FX_TABLE_2      EUR      NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN         NaN
2    3     3  FX_TABLE_1      CNY      CNY  ...   2.0  2.05   2.1  2.15  FX_TABLE_1
3    4     4  FX_TABLE_2      GBP      NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN         NaN
```

or as per your comment:

```
FX_Tab_list = main['FX_Table'].to_list # load table names to the list from Main DF and loop the list
for table in FX_Tab_list:
    dfs_dict[table] = your code lands here
    #for example:
    dfs_dict[table]['difference'] = dfs_dict[table]['2009'] - dfs_dict[table]['2008']
```

Comment: thank you @noobVB for the answer! i am looking for a concept without a merge. Just have a cell in one dataframe, which indicates which other dataframe i have to use. So read this cell in mainframe, get the value e.g. "go to FX_Table_3", open this dataframe FX_TABLE_3, and check the right cell value to calculate the FX-Rates with the Mainframe. 

At the moment i get the call value from the mainframe as a string, 

so means i get this error: 


----> 5 new = FX_Table.filter(items = [Currency], axis=0)
     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filter'

Answer (score 0):

for instance this is the mainframe, but much more easier:

```
main = {
  "EXP": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "EXP2": [1, 2, 3, 4],
  "FX_Table": ["FX_TABLE_5", "FX_TABLE_2","FX_TABLE_3","FX_TABLE_4"],
    "Currency": ["EUR", "EUR", "CNY", "CNY"]
}

#load data into a DataFrame object:
main = pd.DataFrame(main)
```

the fx-rates table for one year is also attached as image[fx_rates_table_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MeM1.png)

so i want to read the mainframe, get the value of the column, e.g. FX_TABLE_2 --> then open the correct FX_TABLE-Dataframe like attached.

at the moment a get a STR-Element, but cannot open with this the correct dataframe, because it is another type.